# Enabling OData Json over WCF Data Services in a Windows Store application

Tags: json, windows-8, wcf-data-services, odata

To achieve higher performance and better service consumption efficiency I am in the process of enabling my WCF Data Services OData server and client to talk to eachother using a json serilization, instead of the default atom.

To achieve this I am modifying my http header as such:

```
args2.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
```

as I can confirm (using Fiddler) that my service is returning my odata stream in a json format.

However, when my Windows 8 Store application client handles the response I receive a

**NotSupportedException** - 'application/json' is currently not supported in Content-Type header

Having read through a few articles online it seems that the version of WCF Data Services I am using should support json serialization.

So what gives? Is it because the client is ignoring the 'odata=verbose' property which enables WCF Data Services 3.0 to run? Or does in fact the Windows.Store WCF Data Services client services library in fact not support json formatting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The JSON Verbose format is not supported by any version of the client assembly. The new JSON (Light) format is supported by the 5.1 version, but I don't think that one has been released in WinRT. What version do you have?

Comment: I have 5.0. As you have mentioned I haven't seen a more recent version for WinRT

Comment: was there ever a solution to this?  Encountering the same exact issue :(

Comment: Hi Mike, I got a response on the MSDN forums - informing me that the WinRT WCF Data Services assemblies are somewhat behind the rest of the stack, so I didn't persue it any further. 

I've moved on since then, but would be still interested if there is a solution. I believe that a new version has been release 5.x - but I haven't checked it out. If you find out, can you let me know?